# Spring get generic type class

Tags: java, spring, generics

I know this question has been asked often but I'm unable to find a solution.
How can I get a generic type class name in a Spring injected repository?

Here it is my base repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, IUserRepository<User>{
   User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

this is the interface

```
public interface IUserRepository<T> {
   public List<T> findAllValidEtSiteAndStructure();
}
```

and finally here it is the implementation

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl<T> implements IUserRepository<T> {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

private Class< T > type;

@Override
public List<T> findAllValidEtSiteAndStructure() {
    final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication instanceof UserAuthentication) {
        final User currentUser = ((UserAuthentication) authentication).getDetails();
        return (List<T>) em.createQuery("FROM " + type.getName()+ " WHERE site=:site AND structure=:structure AND valid=:valid")
                .setParameter("site", currentUser.getInstallation().getSite())
                .setParameter("structure", currentUser.getInstallation().getStructure())
                .setParameter("valid", true)
                .getResultList();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

how can I get type.name? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer to you question can be seen in the documentation -> http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations in the chapter Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories

But I think that should not be necessary in your case. You should be able to do it in the following way.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

   User findByUsername(String username);

   List<User> findByStructureAndSiteAndValid(Structure structure, Site site, boolean valid);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Considering that you're using Spring Framework, use the code snippet bellow, I've tested and it worked just fine:

```
ResolvableType resolvableType = ResolvableType.forClass(UserRepository.class).as(JpaRepository.class);
System.out.println(resolvableType.getGeneric(0));//User
System.out.println(resolvableType.getGeneric(1));//Long
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can't get the generic type because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

What I would do is add an abstract method to `UserRepositoryImpl` that returns the relevant type:

```
public abstract Class getType();
```

And then I would create specific instances for `UserRepositoryImpl` for which the type is already known at compile time. For example:

```
public class StudentRepository extends UserRepositoryImpl<Student> {
  public Class getType() {
    return Student.class;
  }
}
```